# Как можно в ymaps.SuggestView сделать поиск лишь по адресам?

Tags: яндекс-карты

использую ymaps.SuggestView. Все работает хорошо но каким образом можно сделать что бы поисковая строка находила лишь конкретные адреса улиц. Названия городов, сёл , и.т.п не попадали бы в выдачу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Область поиска, в которой предпочтительно искать объект ограничивается прямоугольной областью [boundedBy](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView.html/#SuggestView__param-options.boundedBy), ограничить поиск конкретными населёнными пунктами в API возможности нет.

При необходимости искать по фиксированному списку улиц, правильней будет задать свой провайдер поиска, как это описано в [песочнице](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest) API Яндекс.Карт.

Обратите внимание, использование [SuggestView](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView.html) с бесплатным api-ключом требует отображения результатов запроса на карте Яндекс, как и соблюдение прочих [условий](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/).